# Compute Shaders in Google chrome and Apple M1

Tags: rust, webgl, rust-wasm, webgpu, wgpu-rs

I have a working physics simulator written in wgpu/rust that works when I am running from the command line. However, when I try to run on the chrome v114 (supported according to what I saw online), I get the following error saying the max number of compute workgroups is zero. I printed out my adapter features and i get the following: `Limits {  . . . max_compute_workgroup_storage_size: 0, max_compute_invocations_per_workgroup: 0, max_compute_workgroup_size_x: 0, max_compute_workgroup_size_y: 0, max_compute_workgroup_size_z: 0, max_compute_workgroups_per_dimension: 0, max_push_constant_size: 256 }`

Also, the console dumps the following when the error is thrown:
`Version: WebGL 2.0 (OpenGL ES 3.0 Chromium)`

Am I setting up my adapter wrong? Or does wgpu not support compute shaders in the browser yet? Any advice is welcome. Thanks everyone.

Edit: Just in case this cracks the code, these are my device capabilities whenever I run natively.

````
...
max_compute_workgroup_storage_size: 16384, 
max_compute_invocations_per_workgroup: 256, max_compute_workgroup_size_x: 256, max_compute_workgroup_size_y: 256, max_compute_workgroup_size_z: 64, max_compute_workgroups_per_dimension: 65535, max_push_constant_size: 0 }```
````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wgpu` in Wasm currently supports *either* WebGL 2 *or* WebGPU, but [not both in one build](https://github.com/gfx-rs/wgpu/issues/2804).

Since you are seeing WebGL 2 reported, you have `features = ["webgl"]` activated in your `wgpu` dependency specification; you must remove it to enable WebGPU support instead.

This will not do any harm to compatibility since your application requires compute shaders, which are not part of WebGL 2.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed my cargo.toml and everything is good now.